# Language setting of Visual Studio compromises standard format of Double in Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created some "tab" controls with sloped edges like this:

[Example tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FSXH.jpg)

The sloped edges are basically just triangles (`Polygon`).

To keep things adjustable, I'm defining the **tab height** and the **edge angle** in a `ResourceDictionary` like this:

```
<!-- Height of the Ribbon Tabs in pixels -->
<system:Int32 x:Key="RibbonTabHeight">36</system:Int32>

<!-- Angle of the Ribbon Tabs edges in degrees -->
<system:Double x:Key="RibbonTabEdgeAngle">60.0</system:Double>
```

The **width of the edge** (i.e. the width of the triangle) will be calculated from that by using trigonometry. To do this, I have implemented a converter, so I can use this later on in XAML:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the height of a tab to the width of the sloped edge while retaining the desired angle of the edge
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The tab height shall be passed as the value to be converted
/// The edge angle shall be passed as the converter parameter
/// </remarks>
public class TabHeightToEdgeWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Interpret the passed value as the tab height
        double tabHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);

        // Interpret the passed parameter as the desired angle of the edge
        double edgeAngle = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);

        // Convert degrees in radians
        edgeAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * edgeAngle;

        // The tangent of the edge angle equals the opposite side (tab height) divided by the adjacent side (edge width)
        // Therefore, the edge width equals the tab height divided by the tangent of the edge angle
        double edgeWidth = tabHeight / Math.Tan(edgeAngle);

        return edgeWidth;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For the structure of a tab, I'm using a `Grid` with three columns - first column contains the left edge (triangle), second column contains the actual content of the tab (e.g. the icon) and the third column contains the right edge (triangle).

Putting everything so far together, I have this:

```
<Grid x:Name="RibbonTabGrid"
      Height="{Binding Source={StaticResource RibbonTabHeight}}">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Column 0: Left edge -->
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RibbonTabLeftEdgeGridCell"
                          Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource RibbonTabHeight},
                          Converter={StaticResource TabHeightToEdgeWidthConverter},
                          ConverterParameter={StaticResource RibbonTabEdgeAngle}}"/>

        <!-- ... -->

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

</Grid>
```

However, once I have added the `ConverterParameter` to the binding as shown above, Visual Studio tells me:

**"Input string was not in a correct format"**,

yet everything builds and runs fine.

And here is the funny part: If I change my edge angle definition in the `ResourceDictionary` from `Double` to `Int32` and get rid of the fractional part ("60" instead of "60.0"), then I won't get the "incorrect format" error.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here...

If I use a double hard-coded as the converter parameter like this...

```
<!-- Column 0: Left edge -->
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="RibbonTabLeftEdgeGridCell"
                  Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource RibbonTabHeight},
                  Converter={StaticResource TabHeightToEdgeWidthConverter},
                  ConverterParameter='60.0'}"/>
```

... I also won't get any error. So obviously there is something going wrong throughout the conversion process.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong? I could easily use the `Int32` approach and just forget about this, but I'm eager to know how it's done right...

Let me know if my problem description is incomprehensible or if more information is required. Sorry for all that additional background, I thought it would be best to cover the whole definition-conversion-binding chain.

Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT:** This issue seems to be caused by the language setting of Visual Studio. I've been using Visual Studio with language setting 'German'. In German, decimal commas are used instead of decimal points - but still, in programming, decimal points are used as the common syntax. Visual Studio seems to mix things up when it comes to internal type casts like in bindings. Once I've switched to 'English', the issue did not come up anymore. I'm going to report this to Microsoft. Thanks to @PavelAnikhouski for the hint!

Comment: I've run your sample and suddenly didn't get any errors with `ConverterParameter={StaticResource RibbonTabEdgeAngle}}` Maybe something wrong with xaml designer, you can reload VS and clean you solution. Also check the decimal separator on your OS, maybe it can't recognize the number format

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thank you so much! I think you've pointed me in the right direction. I have updated my original post accordingly.